# Open gnome terminal and execute user-defined zsh command

Tags: zsh, gnome-terminal

I want a command that opens a terminal and executes a function that is defined in my `aliases.zsh`. The function is defined like so:

```
my-function() {
  wget some stuff
  do some other stuff
}
```

I tried `gnome-terminal -- my-function`, but the new terminal reports that it `Failed to execute child process “my-function” (No such file or directory)`. Something similar happens if I do `gnome-terminal -- /bin/zsh -c 'my-function; sleep 1; exec zsh'`: in the new terminal, zsh reports `zsh:1: command not found: my-function`.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/.zshrc` is the customisation file for interactive invocations of `zsh`.

`zsh -c 'some code'` is an inline script. Like for scripts starting with a `#! /bin/zsh -` shebang, thankfully, the `~/.zshrc` is not sourced on startup. If it were, and you had aliases / functions that change the behaviour of standard commands (it's not uncommon to have `alias 'ls=ls --color -F' 'grep=grep --color;`...), that could break zsh scripts.

If you want a script to load `~/.zshrc` or `~/.zprofile` or `/etc/zsh/zshrc`, you need to request it explicitly. But best would be to put those functions in some `~/.zsh/some-library.zsh` and source that instead in the scripts that need it as well as your `~/.zshrc`, or use the `autoload` framework.

```
gnome-terminal -- zsh -c '. ~/.zsh/some-library.zsh; myfunction'
```

If you wanted an interactive zsh to be started in `gnome-terminal` but that first runs your function before issuing the first prompt, you could add a:

```
eval -- $ZSH_INIT_COMMAND
unset ZSH_INIT_COMMAND
```

To the end of your `~/.zshrc`, and run `gnome-terminal` as:

```
gnome-terminal -- env ZSH_INIT_COMMAND='myfunction; echo and whatever else' zsh
```

Or if you wanted to start it as if it had been written at the prompt, so you could handle it the same way, change it to:

```
if (( $+ZLE_INIT )); then
  seed-zle() {
    BUFFER=$ZLE_INIT
    unset ZLE_INIT
    zle -D zle-line-init
    unset -f seed-zle
    zle accept-line
  }
  zle -N zle-line-init seed-zle
fi
```

And start gnome-terminal as:

```
gnome-terminal -- env ZLE_INIT='myfunction; echo and whatever else' zsh
```